# Create GridView with margin for each cell programmatically

Tags: android, android-gridview, programmatically-created

I would like to create a dynamic gridview programmaticaly. All things look good. But the margin for each cell is not displayed. Please help.

PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Calendar viewData = getData(position);
    GridView gridView = new GridView(mContext);
    gridView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(mContext, viewData);
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    container.addView(view);
    return gridView;
}
```

GridAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cal_single_cell, parent, false);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(2, 2));
    TextView lblDisplay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lbl_cell_name);
    lblDisplay.setText(getDisplayText(position));

    if(CalendarConverter.dateCompare(getData(position), Calendar.getInstance(), VIEW_LEVEL) == 0){
        layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.backgorund_current_cell));
    }
    return layout;
}
```

And my cal_single_cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/CalendarSingleCell">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_cell_name"
        android:text="Jan"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[view display result on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-vGxGh5ega8ZE9IZnpXS3VTQ2s)

Comment: Hi @NguyenDang, i answered on your problem, but no response, no information that my answer helped you or not. If my answer help then please set it is right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Maciej Sikora, It still not work for me, when I say:
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cal_single_cell, parent, false);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(2, 2));
I got a white page.
And I see ViewHolder is a really good for performance. Thank you.

Comment: Paste Your current code, i will help You, I see in comment that You are doing it all the time wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your main mistake is that You want to change cell margin and instead of this change GridView margin.

Use GridView attributes **android:horizontalSpacing**, **android:verticalSpacing**. More info in this question - [Increase the grid spacing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871430/increase-the-grid-spacing-in-android)

Or change margin,padding of view inside row view ( Every cell view ). Programically in Adapters **getView** method do something like that:

```
view.setLayoutParams(/* your layout params */); //where view is cell view
```

In You code:

```
@Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cal_single_cell, parent, false);

    //****************************
    //here set padding or margin

    layout.setLayoutParams(/* your layout params */);

    //***************************
    TextView lblDisplay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lbl_cell_name);
    lblDisplay.setText(getDisplayText(position));

    if(CalendarConverter.dateCompare(getData(position), Calendar.getInstance(), VIEW_LEVEL) == 0){
        layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.backgorund_current_cell));
    }
    return layout;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

Changing layout parameters in every getView is very not optimal, if You must do it then create ViewHolder.

Comment: Hi @Maciej Sikora, Thank for your support
I just add GridView.LayoutParams to each cell in my GridView in my updated post. And I hope that enough information for you. Thank you very much.